# MySQL Access denied to root user

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-workbench

i have recently installed MySQL `*Ver 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))*`

after installation when i try to access my shell its showing

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

both with or without sudo, i know this has answers on stack and other forums but none seems to help me, i have tried reinstalling MySQL server but that also didn't help, i tried skip grant option and then changing root password but that failed as well , need help in this , thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can reset the password with one downtime. Just simply follow the below steps for 8 version.

1. Stop the Mysql service
   $ systemctl stop mysql
2. Now run Mysql service with skip grant tables mode.
   $ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
3. Now login the service
   $ mysql -uroot
4. execute flush privileges query
5. execute alter query
   $ alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
6. Now stop the mysql service
   $ systemctl stop mysql
7. now restart the mysql service
   $ systemctl restart mysql
8. Now try to login using the updated password